Referencing a pitched pointer in device function CUDA
I have created a 3D matrix using cudaMalloc3D using cudaPitchedPtr, I would like to reference the created matrix from a device function as well. Does copying the pitched pointer into __device__ cudaPitchedPtr and then referencing it work? For example -
cudaPitchedPtr rho_pitchedPtr;

__device__ int doSomethingWithRho() {

rho_ptr = rho_pitchedPtr.ptr;

//use rho_ptr

}
int main() {

cudaMalloc3D(rho_pitchedPtr,...);


}

I cannot reference rho_pitchedPtr directly in __device__ function. Any way I can do it?

The use of a pitchedPointer is documented in the cuda programming guide: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html
Search for cudaMalloc3D there and look for the code sample, it shows exactly how to use the pitchedPointer in device code.

You can pass cudaPitchedPtr structure  by value as an argument to the kernel and use it directly in the kernel

Something like this should work:
cudaPitchedPtr rho_pitchedPtr;

__device__ int doSomethingWithRho(cudaPitchedPtr myrho) {

  void *rho_ptr = myrho.ptr;  // you would actually use something like int * or float *

  //use rho_ptr

}

__global__ void k(cudaPitchedPtr myrho){

  doSomethingWithRho(myrho);}
  
int main() {

  cudaMalloc3D(&rho_pitchedPtr,...);
  k<<<1,1>>>(rho_pitchedPtr);
}

You won't be able to use the rho_pitchedPtr as you have shown it directly in device code without passing it through a parameter list as I have shown.  In general, host-based variables (which is what rho_pitchedPtr is), even at global scope, cannot be directly referenced in device code, except for exceptions for global-scope const variables.  The const variable exception is not applicable to structures (which is what rho_pitchedPtr is) and furthermore you wouldn't be able to make sensible use of it as a const variable anyway.
If you want to be able to use a global-scope variable in both host and device code, another approach would be to mark it with __managed__, creating a statically allocated managed memory entity:
__managed__ cudaPitchedPtr rho_pitchedPtr;

__device__ int doSomethingWithRho() {

  void *rho_ptr = rho_pitchedPtr.ptr;  // you would actually use something like int * or float *

  //use rho_ptr

}

__global__ void k(){

  doSomethingWithRho();}
  
int main() {

  cudaMalloc3D(&rho_pitchedPtr,...);
  k<<<1,1>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}


Everytime a device function is called, is the PitchedPtr copied into the device memory from the host memory? If I want frequent access to PitchedPtr, can I create device cudaPitchedPtr and copy the contents of the pitchedPtr into the device memory before the execution begins? Then can I reference the device PitchedPtr for device functions and the other one for host functions? Does this work?

If we are talking about the first method, the pointer is only copied at the point of the kernel call, using a typical pass-by-value C++ mechanism for all function call arguments.  no copying after that.  If we are talking about the second method, the pointer is copied to the device either at the point of the kernel call or when you first access it.  Thereafter it is not repeatedly copied to the device.  It will be copied to the host once you access it again on the host.
